# Several MDHA Build Errors

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, whitespace, visual-studio-cordova

I have VS_2013 Update 2 with CTP1.1 ; Win8.1 x64 ; Hyper-V enabled intel i3; 50GB *almost full* C Drive thanks to visual studio solely.

I am tired off by back to back errors in MDHA so i thought to ask community in once. Do anyone have idea to solve these bunch of errors.

My System Vars-

ADT_HOME -> C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

ANT_HOME -> C:\apache-ant-1.9.3

GIT_HOME -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd

JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

JDK_HOME -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

Path -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;%ADT_HOME%\tools;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\

**WindowsPhone Emulator720P Error -**

Error   2   The command ""C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows Phone" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "SampleHybridApp" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "PhoneEmulator720P"" exited with code 8.    C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets   68  5   SampleHybridApp

*Output-*

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SampleHybridApp, Configuration: Debug Windows Phone ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(90,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.29 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: Z:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\0kudwm0m.p2t\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Build settings:
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Windows Phone
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: wp8
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: SampleHybridApp
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp
1>  ------    buildTarget: PhoneEmulator720P
1>  ------ App dir Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug already exists
1>  ------ Copying app files to www
1>  ------ Done copying app files to www
1>  ------ Copying res files
1>  ------ Done copying res files
1>  ------ Adding platform: wp8
1>  cordova library for "wp8" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
1>  Checking if platform "wp8" passes minimum requirements...
1>  Checking wp8 requirements...
1>  Running ""C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\.cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.4.0\wp8\bin\check_reqs"" (output to follow)
1>  
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>  CordovaError: Requirements check failed: The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  
1>  
1>      at C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\src\metadata\wp8_parser.js:61:22
1>      at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:651:7)
1>      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
1>      at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
1>      at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:968:11)
1>      at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
1>      at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
1>C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(68,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows Phone" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "SampleHybridApp" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "PhoneEmulator720P"" exited with code 8.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Windows *AnyCPU, ARM, x85, x64* Simulator Error -**

Error   2   Could not find 'check_reqs.js' in 'bin' folder, aborting... Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\EXEC  1   1   SampleHybridApp

Error   3   The command ""C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows-AnyCPU" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "SampleHybridApp" "--AnyCPU"" exited with code 8.  C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets   65  5   SampleHybridApp

*Output-*

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SampleHybridApp, Configuration: Debug Windows-AnyCPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(90,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.29 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: Z:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\0kudwm0m.p2t\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Build settings:
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Windows-AnyCPU
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: windows8
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: SampleHybridApp
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp
1>  ------ App dir Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug already exists
1>  ------ Copying app files to www
1>  ------ Done copying app files to www
1>  ------ Copying res files
1>  ------ Done copying res files
1>  ------ Adding platform: windows8
1>  cordova library for "windows8" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
1>  Checking if platform "windows8" passes minimum requirements...
1>  Checking windows8 requirements...
1>  Running ""C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\.cordova\lib\windows8\cordova\3.4.0\windows8\bin\check_reqs"" (output to follow)
1>  4.0.30319
1>  
1>  
1>  
1>  C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>  CordovaError: Requirements check failed: 4.0.30319
1>  
1>  
1>  
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  
1>EXEC : error : Could not find 'check_reqs.js' in 'bin' folder, aborting...
1>  
1>  
1>      at C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\src\metadata\windows8_parser.js:65:22
1>      at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:651:7)
1>      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
1>      at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
1>      at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:968:11)
1>      at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
1>      at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
1>C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(65,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Windows-AnyCPU" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "SampleHybridApp" "--AnyCPU"" exited with code 8.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Android Emulator Error -**

Error   2   NAND: could not write file C:\Users\VISHAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\TMP8CA7.tmp, No space left on device   SampleHybridApp

*Output-*

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SampleHybridApp, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(90,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.29 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: Z:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\0kudwm0m.p2t\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Build settings:
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: SampleHybridApp
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
1>  ------ App dir Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug already exists
1>  ------ Copying app files to www
1>  ------ Done copying app files to www
1>  ------ Copying res files
1>  ------ Done copying res files
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying platform merge files from Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\merges\android to merges\android
1>  ------ Done copying platform merge files to merges\android
1>  ------ Certificate copy from Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\res\cert\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying certificate files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: 
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins: 
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins: 
1>  ------ Copying Icons and Splashscreens for: android
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to platforms\android\res\drawable\icon.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  ------ Successfully copied  res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  ------ Building platform: android
1>  ------ Configuration options: --debug
1>  cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "SampleHybridApp"
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.SampleHybridApp"
1>  Running command: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug 
1>  Buildfile: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\build.xml
1>    [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.
1>  
1>  -set-mode-check:
1>  
1>  -set-debug-files:
1>  
1>  -check-env:
1>   [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.0
1>   [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
1>  
1>  -setup:
1>       [echo] Project Name: SampleHybridApp
1>    [gettype] Project Type: Application
1>  
1>  -set-debug-mode:
1>  
1>  -debug-obfuscation-check:
1>  
1>  -pre-build:
1>  
1>  -build-setup:
1>  [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
1>       [echo] Resolving Build Target for SampleHybridApp...
1>  [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
1>  [gettarget] API level:        19
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Resolving Dependencies for SampleHybridApp...
1>  [dependency] Library dependencies:
1>  [dependency] 
1>  [dependency] ------------------
1>  [dependency] Ordered libraries:
1>  [dependency] 
1>  [dependency] ------------------
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
1>    [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.
1>  
1>  nodeps:
1>  
1>  -set-mode-check:
1>  
1>  -set-debug-files:
1>  
1>  -check-env:
1>   [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.0
1>   [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
1>  
1>  -setup:
1>       [echo] Project Name: CordovaLib
1>    [gettype] Project Type: Android Library
1>  
1>  -set-debug-mode:
1>  
1>  -debug-obfuscation-check:
1>  
1>  -pre-build:
1>  
1>  -build-setup:
1>  [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
1>       [echo] Resolving Build Target for CordovaLib...
1>  [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
1>  [gettarget] API level:        19
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Resolving Dependencies for CordovaLib...
1>  [dependency] Library dependencies:
1>  [dependency] No Libraries
1>  [dependency] 
1>  [dependency] ------------------
1>  
1>  -code-gen:
1>  [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
1>  [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
1>  [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
1>       [echo] Handling aidl files...
1>       [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Handling Resources...
1>       [aapt] Found new input file
1>       [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
1>  [buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.
1>  
1>  -pre-compile:
1>  
1>  -compile:
1>       [echo] Creating library output jar file...
1>  
1>  -post-compile:
1>  
1>  -obfuscate:
1>  
1>  -dex:
1>       [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...
1>  
1>  -crunch:
1>     [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\res
1>     [crunch] To destination dir: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\res
1>     [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache
1>  
1>  -package-resources:
1>       [echo] Library project: do not package resources...
1>  
1>  -package:
1>       [echo] Library project: do not package apk...
1>  
1>  -post-package:
1>  
1>  -do-debug:
1>       [echo] Library project: do not create apk...
1>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
1>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
1>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
1>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\build.prop
1>  
1>  -post-build:
1>  
1>  debug:
1>  
1>  -code-gen:
1>  [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
1>  [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
1>  [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
1>       [echo] Handling aidl files...
1>       [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Handling Resources...
1>       [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
1>       [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
1>  [buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.
1>  
1>  -pre-compile:
1>       [echo] Set jars path to: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar
1>  
1>  -compile:
1>      [javac] Compiling 2 source files to Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\classes
1>  
1>  -post-compile:
1>  
1>  -obfuscate:
1>  
1>  -dex:
1>        [dex] input: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\classes
1>        [dex] input: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar
1>        [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-a07219ee309f201b364ac49a13a65c21.jar <- Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build\classes.jar
1>        [dex] Found Deleted Target File
1>        [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\classes.dex...
1>         [dx] Merged dex A (7 defs/2.2KiB) with dex B (205 defs/312.8KiB). Result is 212 defs/383.9KiB. Took 0.1s
1>  
1>  -crunch:
1>     [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res
1>     [crunch] To destination dir: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Processing image to cache: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\res\drawable\icon.png => Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable\icon.png
1>     [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\res\drawable\icon.png: 0% size of source)
1>     [crunch] Crunched 13 PNG files to update cache
1>  
1>  -package-resources:
1>       [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
1>       [aapt] Creating full resource package...
1>  
1>  -package:
1>  [apkbuilder] Found Deleted Target File
1>  [apkbuilder] Creating SampleHybridApp-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
1>  
1>  -post-package:
1>  
1>  -do-debug:
1>   [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
1>       [echo] Debug Package: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\SampleHybridApp-debug.apk
1>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
1>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
1>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
1>  [propertyfile] Updating property file: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\build.prop
1>  
1>  -post-build:
1>       [move] Moving 1 file to Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build
1>       [move] Moving 1 file to Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\CordovaLib\ant-build
1>  
1>  debug:
1>  
1>  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
1>  Total time: 15 seconds
1>  Command finished with error code 0: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug,
1>  ------ Copying back to project: Android
1>  ------ Done copying compiled files Android
1>  ------ Checking for: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bin\Android\Debug\CordovaApp.build.appxrecipe
2>------ Deploy started: Project: SampleHybridApp, Configuration: Debug Android ------
2>  ------ current directory: Z:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
2>  cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
2>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
2>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
2>  Wrote out Android application name to "SampleHybridApp"
2>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.SampleHybridApp"
2>  Running command: Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --nobuild --emulator
2>  Skipping build...
2>  WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to TestAVD
2>  Waiting for emulator...
2>NAND: could not write file C:\Users\VISHAL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP8CA7.tmp, No space left on device
```

Comment: could you send an email to the team multidevicehybridapp@microsoft.com - they should be able to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure following features are installed. You can check or modify through Add\Remove program for VS 2013

- Tools for Maintaining Store apps for Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.0 SDK